# TMediaPlayer Error - Unsupported Media File

Tags: delphi, media-player, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I am trying to play a mp3 file from Firemonkey XE7 windows application. It should have been a simple task by putting a TMediaPlayer component, assigning it a .mp3 file, and just playing it.  However, I get the following error:

```
Application Error
Exception EReadError in module MediaPlayerTest.exe at 00000000000012139E.
Error reading MediaPlayer1.FileName: Unsupported media file testfile.mp3.
```

I have also tried .wav, and it didn't work either. 
(Audio codec have already been installed and the media files can successfully be played by windows media player.)

I then try compiling the very same program on another computer, and it can be compiled successfully and the mp3 plays just fine.

Does anyone know why it doesn't compile on one computer but does on another?

Comment: "compiling the very same program on another computer" - What about compiling on the problematic computer and then running it on the working computer? Does that work? This shouldn't be a compiling error at all, it's a runtime error. "Doesn't compile" makes no sense with the error message you provided. Do you understand what "compiling" means?

Comment: Your question is unclear. It apparently *compiles* on both computers, or you couldn't run it successfully on one and get a runtime error on the other. You can't get a runtime error on code that *doesn't compile*.

Comment: I am sorry I did not fully understand what compile means because I normally just simply click on Run.  If I do it separately, the program does compile but doesn't run (with the exception shown above).
If the program is compiled on another computer and run on the previously problematic computer, it still works perfectly(plays sound on both computer).

Comment: It sounds like you need to learn some more about how programming works. It seems (based on the comments) that you have code running in your form's constructor which is trying to load and play the file immediately. We can't see your code, so we have no idea what exactly you're doing. You need to provide a very simple short program (code) for us which recreates your issue. Even then, this seems like a problem that will be very difficult for us to track down, even if we had your full source code. It's definitely related to how Windows recognizes file types (based on your problem description).

Comment: This page (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Media.TMediaPlayer) suggests you need to use wav. This one (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Media.TMediaCodecManager) suggests mp3 is fine. I think you need to know where the codec support is coming from in this platform.

Answer (score 1):

XE7 used DirectX for audio/video playback.  Likely something is messed up with your directx installation.  I noticed this problem first on a VMWare virtual machine, TMediaPlayer is unable to play anything all file types are unsupported.  However same program running on my host worked fine.

Try reinstalling DirectX.

Comment: I can confirm this on D10.2 with VMWare 12.5.7. Haven't found a solution to this yet. Anyone knows more on this?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here  In a VM, host machine.. tested on a few other PC's as well with the same result.  Delphi 10.2.

I tracked it down to TWindowsMedia.InitVideoMixingRenderer9 in FMX.Media.Win which includes this in calculating Result:

Succeeded(FVMRFilterConfig9.SetRenderingMode(VMR9Mode_Windowless));

GetLastError returns 126,

```
ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND
126 (0x7E)
The specified module could not be found.
```

Changing that call to pass in VMR9Mode_Renderless works (at least for me).  I didn't dig into the why/what of this. I'm also just playing audio, no video.

Just thought I'd pass along a workaround in case it's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a limitation of Direct X when installed in a VM. I installed a different media codec ([the basic k-lite codec pack](http://www.codecguide.com/)) and the player worked fine after that without any code changes. Also, filed a [bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-24840) so hopefully R&D can address it

Answer (score 0):

I've got some very similar errors.

And there are more than one cases:

1. Problem in mp3. Some Mp3 is unsopported by standard TMediaPlayer. May be it can be fixed by registering of your codec (view list item 3)
2. If you tried to use TMedia you can't open any media file until
   you not created TMediaPlayer in any place of your code and filled
   its FileName property. It's very strange, because
   `TMediaCodecManager.RegisterMediaCodecClass('.mp3', SVMP3Files,
   TMediaType.Audio, TWindowsMediaCodec);` is called if you have
   **FMX.Media** in uses.
3. Problems in codecs. You can find example in **FMX.Media.Win** unit, how to register new codec for your app.

Hope this information will help you.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with XE7, but in earlier versions the TMediaplayer used the windows mediaplayer. So the behaviour relies on the actual installed version of the windows player on the computer. This explains the different behaviour on the two computer. 
You also can use an external player such as real player or other. Use shellexecute to start the external player. Third party player give more details to run mp3.

Comment: Is this a firemonkey answer?

Comment: This is a TMediaplayer Delphi answer

Comment: Which one? FMX TMediaPlayer or VCL TMediaPlayer?

Comment: My experience is limited on vcl (2009 and earlier), but I had similiar problems on which I spend much time and I think it is worth to look at the windows player, because it seems to work on one computer and on one computer not. How would you explain that this could be a firemonkey problem?

Comment: It's a FireMonkey question. The control you are talking about is not the control in the question.