# Notification Sound not being changed in Windows VCL

Tags: delphi

I am trying to change the TNotification sound in my Delphi VCL application.

```
  try
    ANotification := ANotificationCenter.CreateNotification;
    ANotification.Name := NAME_NTC_NOVA_SOLICITACAO;
    ANotification.Title := Title;
    ANotification.AlertBody := Body;
    ANotification.EnableSound := True;
    ANotification.SoundName := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'sound\eventually.mp3';
    ANotificationCenter.PresentNotification(ANotification);  
  finally
    ANotification.Free;
  end;
```

As the [Using TNotification](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Using_Notifications) documentation says, the sound file need to be dropped in the Project Window and then configure the Project -> Deployment. I already did these things.

My notification sound `sound\eventually.mp3` is already placed in the right path. But the windows default notification sound keeps the same.

**UPDATE:** `ANotificationCenter` was just dropped in the form at design time, nothing was changed in this component.

Comment: Not relevant to your actual question, but you MUST let `ANotification := ANotificationCenter.CreateNotification` be the line immediately BEFORE the `try`. Otherwise, if `ANotification` is a local variable which you haven't used before (typically the case), you will do `ANotification.Free` on a random pointer `ANotification` if an exception occurs on this line. That's very bad. Only if you are lucky will you get an (embarrassing) AV.

Comment: Did you try with a wav file instead of mp3?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I usually don't do that, it was just a distraction, but thanks! Olivier wav file did not work.

Comment: How is `ANotificationCenter` declared and created?  This is missingg from your q and should be in it.

Comment: Thank you @MartynA I edited the question

Comment: You might take a look at [this q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28910428/tmediaplayer-error-unsupported-media-file) just in case it is relevant.

Comment: I ended up disabling the notification sound `ANotification.EnableSound := False;` and playing a media file by myself using `sndPlaySound('...\eventually.wav'), SND_ASYNC);`

Answer (score 0):

As I didn't find an answer, I ended up disabling the notification sound and playing a media file by my self which simulates the notification sound.

Not the solution I was looking for, but it is working pretty well.

```
uses
  Winapi.MMSystem;
...
  try
    ANotification := ANotificationCenter.CreateNotification;
    ANotification.Name := NAME_NTC_NOVA_SOLICITACAO;
    ANotification.Title := Title;
    ANotification.AlertBody := Body;    
    ANotification.EnableSound := False;
    sndPlaySound(PWideChar(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'sound\eventually.wav'), SND_ASYNC);
    ANotificationCenter.PresentNotification(ANotification);  
  finally
    ANotification.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: In documentation, there is: "In the case of Windows, the notification sound always plays; even if you disable the sound with EnableSound." Are you sure that disabling really works? I still hear the default sound. :(

Comment: It keeps the default sound, but I needed the user to hear my application sound to know when the order was finished. Couldn't find a solution, unfortunately this was what fit my customer need.